# htaccess conditional rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im using an MVC framework for my PHP application which works great.  I have the below code in a .htaccess file in the root folder of my application.  This redirects everything to the public folder which is causing issues for me.  I want to apply the below to everyfolder apart from one.  How would I go about doing this?  ie.  need to access the /dompdf/ directory and all subdirectories normally wihtout the below rule which redirects.

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
# </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if I understand what you want, this should help -

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^dompdf    [L,NC]
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]    
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
# </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing code with this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^(dompdf|public)/)^.*$ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Negative lookahead will prevent application of these rules for paths `dompdf` and `public`.